# How to use Redux Promise Middleware with slices in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-promise-middleware

I'm using the `slices` feature of Redux Toolkit. As you may know, one slice returns an `action` for every created `reducer`.

I want to use the `redux-promise-middleware` library, which for a given `ACTION_TYPE`, it creates three possible new actions: `ACTION_TYPE_FETCHING`, `ACTION_TYPE_FULFILLED`, and `ACTION_TYPE_REJECTED`. How do I handle this from the point of view of the `slices`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to add the expected action types to the `extraReducers` section of `createSlice`, like:

```js
// could use a predefined action constant if desired:
const actionFetching = "ACTION_TYPE_FETCHING"

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // specific case reducers here
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // could use computed key syntax with a separate type constant
    [actionFetching ]: (state, action) => {}
    // or the actual field name directly matching the type string
    ACTION_TYPE_FULFILLED: (state, action) => {}
  }
})
```